# Is the number 166684 real in the reputation league all time?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

In the [reputation league all time for SO](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), the number 166684 occurs four times, I just can't believe the odds of this number to be real. But 166684(hex 0x28B1C) doesn't look strange, doesn't look like overflow.

Is it real?

[image: Reputation Change]

[image: Total Reputation]

Comment: Oooh, you caught something ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an artifact of requiring more than 200 reputation to be tracked in the leagues in the first place.  Perhaps we should change that table a bit.

Comment: What to... *You users aren't important enough to get tracked*? Or *We don't like you enough to count you*? :P

Comment: So, there's exactly that many with 200+, and it's showing up like that because we're counting 0 people from 1-199 rep?

Comment: @DennisMeng Correct, 0-199 are not included in change tracking